# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Y

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am working on docker application using PHP and MySql. While accessing MySql using command line, I am facing an error:-

MY docker-compose file:
version : '2'

```
services:

  web:
   image : php:7.0-apache
   build : ./app
   volumes :
    - "./app:/var/www/html"

   ports:
    - "5000:80"

   links:
     - mysqlserver

   mysqlserver:
   image : mysql

   ports:
     - "3307:3306"

   environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : rootpass
    MYSQL_DATABASE : test_db
   volumes:
    - "/var/lib/mysql"
```

I entered the MySQL container and enter `MySQL -u root -p` and entered password but am facing this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: Y
>   ES)

How can i access test_db database in container via command line or some other way? Thanks

Comment: You have to allow root logins from remote locations in mysql: http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply..let me check..